# Convert png to dds with python?

Tags: python, png, dds-format

Need to convert 50 images, and doing it manually would be too long.
Сan't find a library with such function.

I tried Pillow, but it can't save in dds.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I can use the command line app in python, so image magic covers all my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/) library:

```
from wand import image

with image.Image(filename='your.png') as img:
    img.compression = 'dxt5'
    img.save(filename='your.dds')
```

Comment: Using Python3 I had to modify this a bit

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this library might be useful for you, check it out: https://github.com/ducakar/img2dds

Answer (score 0):

In regards to @Yuri Leonov post above. In Python3 I had to specify reading mode in open() command to get it to work.

```
from wand import image

with image.Image(filename=r'yourimage.png') as img:
    img.compression = 'dxt5'
    img.save(filename='yourimage.dds')
```

Comment: Do you mean the letter `r` before the string? That's Python [raw-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).